# Call component's action from controller's action

Tags: ember.js

```
Controller Name : mailPDF

actions: {
// from the action sendmailPDF of the mailPDF controller I want to call the action name as "send" of the "Sendmail" Component.

    sendEmailPDF: function () {
    // want to call a component's action ex. SENDMAIL component and its send action()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pss As i have told i want to call the conponet's action (method) from controller's Action. For ex. i am in the controller called xyz and want to call a method abc() which is defined in the other component plz feel free to ask me to avoid the confusion !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember has a very strict data down, actions up methodology, your controller has no direct link/knowledge of children components.

Either you can add an observer in your component, watching some property that was attached, and as that property changes, you fire the action within your component.  Or your component can send an action out registering itself with it's parent controller, giving the controller a reference to itself in order for you to make the call.

Free-handing here:

#### Component

```
setup: function(){
   this.sendAction('registerWithParent', this);
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

#### Controller

```
actions: {
  registerPDFComp: function(comp){
     this.set('pdfComp', comp);
  } 
}
```

#### Template

```
{{pdf-comp registerWithParent=registerPDFComp}}
```

In the example, you'd be able to then use the `pdfComp` property to access the component, and call it's action.  It breaks a ton of principles, single responsibility, yadda yadda yadda.  But maybe you've got a good reason.

Comment: @kingping2k thank you for the reply !! can you please show me example how can i use it on Boolean value change because i can implement this need with observer easily.